# Assigning multiple values from a JFormattedTextField to multiple variables

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jformattedtextfield

If I had a `JFormattedTextField` like this

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("#,#");
JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

and if I had variables

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
```

how can I store the first number in the textfield to `x`, and the second number to `y`?

Comment: What 'second' number?  A single `JFormattedTextField` contains a single number at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first & second numbers are those either side of the comma `,` in the `JFormattedTextField`, you could do:

```
String[] numbers = textField.getText().split(",");
int x = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The mask does not change how the inner value is stored, it just tells how to represent/input it.

So you still have a `.getText()` which returns a String in the format of your election. Process that String (`split()`, `StringTokenizer`) as you see fit.